# Flash player issue on CM 10.1

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.2-jelly-bean, adobe-flash

I recently flashed my HTC ONE X ATT with **CyanogenMod 10.1** and noticed that Flash Player is not installed. I tried to find it on Google Play, but it says that Flash is not compatible with my handset.

How can I install Flash Player on my handset, so flash content works on all my browsers (Browser, Dolphin, Firefox and Chrome)?

I manually installed Flash Player 11.1.115.36 for Android 4.0, but it's only working on Firefox.

Comment: Chrome for Android doesn't support Flash Player (and [it's never going to](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/faq)), so you're kind of out of luck there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download flash from here: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html.

The stock browser is best but if you can't use that Firefox is 2nd when it comes to

Comment: as I mentioned, I have already installed one and its working on morzilla only and it doesn't mean I have to use morzilla only. For my different purposes, I have to use several browsers, i.e. not only morzilla or only browser

Comment: @hsuk Have you checked that plug-ins are enabled on the stock browser? Menu>Settings>Advanced>Enable Plug-ins if you haven't.

Comment: yeah, its enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The following browsers does not support Flash:

- Chrome (as mentioned by eldarerathis)
- Dolphin (because it crashes the browser)

I think UC Browser no longer supports flash video as well.

Comment: Dolphin is considered as the efficient browser for android and how can it be now without flash player...

Comment: @hsuk Go to `Settings > Web content > Flash player`. It will say "Adobe has officially discontinued support for Flash Player on Android. Playing Flash will crash Dolphin so we have turned it off to ensure the most stable browsing experience. Read more on the Adobe website, or change to iPhone User Agent to watch videos on HTML5 websites."

Comment: thanks for the info but they should have fix the bug instead getting it discontinued.

Comment: @hsuk It's not a bug. It's just the way it is. We're moving towards HTML5, instead of Flash (which is quite outdated). Flash is also useless when you're trying to do Search Engine Optimization on websites.

Comment: That's fine but what about the those websites which are already using flash player.

Comment: @husk That's their problem. If people can't see their site, it's their loss. Hehehe.

Comment: :) that could be loss for us too